# Replace & Update all rows sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table called **Players** and columns **Name**, **PlayerID**. I am using **sqlite** under *DB Browser for SQLite*.

Unfortunately, all my player's names have a something like a "\n" **(turned out to be a /r)** at the end of the name.

Ex:

```
"Mark
"
```

I tried to Update & Replace all the names with the following query (I have like 450 rows in the table):

```
UPDATE Players
SET Name = REPLACE(Name,CHAR(10),'')
WHERE PlayerID <= 500
```

When I execute something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Players
WHERE Players.Name LIKE 'Mark'
```

it'll return no rows because of the end line.

I want to change all my rows from this format

```
"Mark
"
```

to this

```
"Mark"
```

and save all the changes.

How can I solve my problem? What's wrong?

Comment: Did you try `LIKE '%Mark%'` ?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, that works. But I want to remove all my white space after my string. I also tried with RTRIM.

Comment: So, what other white space characters have you got in there, besides the `\n`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I also have spaces. Some of them look like the example above (with Mark) and some of them look like this "Mark     " and at the end of the spaces it also has a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove all line feed characters (`\n`), then what you have is ok. You could also remove the `WHERE`, to update all rows:

```
UPDATE Players
SET Name = REPLACE(Name, CHAR(10), '')
-- WHERE PlayerID <= 500
;
```

Similarly, if you want to remove **all** spaces, do the same:

```
UPDATE Players
SET Name = REPLACE(Name, ' ', '')
-- WHERE PlayerID <= 500
;
```

**Beware** though that the above will change `'Mark Jenkins'` to `'MarkJenkins'`. Are you sure you want to do that?

---

You could also do both actions in a single statement, with:

```
SET Name = REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, CHAR(10), ''), ' ', '')
```

---

Before running the actual update, you could examine the changes with:

```
SELECT Name,
       REPLACE(Name, CHAR(10), '') AS NewName_NoLinefeed,
       REPLACE(Name, ' ', '') AS NewName_NoSpace,
       REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, CHAR(10), ''), ' ', '')
           AS NewName_NoLinefeed_NoSpace
FROM Players
-- WHERE PlayerID <= 500
;
```

Comment: That's still not working :(. It does say that my rows are affected, but the changes are not saved.

Comment: Did it work in the end? Can you give us a sample of the row - if it didn't?

Comment: Well it didn't, but your answer was right for my question. I run the query, it says all my rows are affected but when I check if the changes are saved they aren't. It looks like it does nothing. I mean the update isn't really updating the rows.

Comment: I tried in [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=7b9391de3a27b8ab9445b27e14f17b13) and it works. Are you sure you had CHAR(10) there? Can you show us which UPDATE statement did you try and also show us a row that was not updated?

Comment: Can the version of sqlite affect this?

Comment: I don't think REPLACE has changed through versions. Perhaps you have `/r` characters as well. `CHAR(13)`

Comment: Yes, that was! It was `/r`. Thanks so much!